# How do I change matching brackets color's highlighting in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, highlight, brackets, braces

I'm using VS-Code color theme on IntelliJ, and when I place my cursor within a few nested brackets, it becomes almost invisible since the highlighting is the same color as my cursor (see the [screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtCsR.png)).

[image: Cursor and brackets highlighting are almost indistinguishable]

I've found `Settings => Editor -> Code Editing -> Matched Brace` but I want to keep the highlighting, and change it's color.
And the options in `Settings => Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Code -> Matched Brace` change the settings brackets style when they're not selected, which is not the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | **Matched brace** works fine here. Make sure to change the **Foreground** property or remove any **Effects**.

The color used in your example when the caret is not placed on the parentheses is set via Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Braces and Operators | **Parentheses**.